# While opening the dialog box in javascript with nicEdit I have a trouble?

Tags: javascript, nicedit

I am using `nicEdit` to display content. In this I am getting content from jqGrid. while opening the `nicEdit` dialog box using `javascript` first time, `nicEdit` shows empty without content.

And closed the dialog box and reopen it shows the content. while second time opening the dialog box the firebug throws an error

```
TypeError: b.removeInstance is not a function
```

How i will solve this error and how i get the content value while opening the first time of dialog box?

Here Some code I am Using in Javascript

```
$(".nicEdit-main").empty();       
$(".nicEdit-main").append(JopInlinetext);        
jQuery("#addInLineItem").dialog("open");     
new nicEditor({maxHeight : 220}).panelInstance('lineItemId');
```

Comment: can you add some debugging there, such as `console.log(JopInlinetext)` right before the `.append()` call? It's probably that the variable is uninitialized on the first call.

Comment: First call itself the content will be initialized.. before append i given an alert(JopInlinetext); content is there.